# Python index out of range error

Tags: python, loops, debugging, indexing

Not sure why i'm getting the index out of range error.

Function should loop the ip list until the event values are over:

```
event = ["Birthday-venues", "baby-shower", "wedding", "corp", "party"]
ip = [1, 2, 3]

lip = len(ip)
levent = len(event)


def eventIP():
    i = 0
    dict = {}
    while i < levent:
        for j in range(0, lip):
            dict[event[i]] = ip[j]
            if i < levent:
                i += 1
            else:
                break

    print(dict)

eventIP()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 21, in <module>
    eventIP()
  File "script.py", line 13, in eventIP
    dict[event[i]] = ip[j]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What do you expect this to actually do?

Comment: what are the values of i and j when it crashes?

Comment: What about `levent = len(event)-1`? If you do this then the output will be `{'Birthday-venues': 1, 'party': 2, 'baby-shower': 2, 'corp': 1, 'wedding': 3}`.

Comment: It kind of looks like you're trying to create a dictionary like `{'Birthday-venues':1, 'Birthday-venues':2, 'Birthday-venues':3, 'baby-shower':1...}`. Is that the case?

Comment: not exactly, but I was able to find the solution to the error, thanks for your help :)

Comment: I ask because you're repeatedly assigning new values to the same keys in a loop. Since dictionary keys are unique, that'll just end with a dictionary like `{'Birthday-venues':3, 'baby-shower':3...}`, with `3` as the value for each key, which kind of defeats the purpose of the `list` named `ip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It crashes because you test whether i is smaller than levent before updating it. Try the following:

```
    i += 1
    if i >= levent:
        break
```